# Multiple table export in oracle

Tags: oracle, export

Is it possible to export multiple tables in oracle using QUERY parameter the WHERE clauses are different for each table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the old export (`exp`) then no, you'd need to do a separate export for each table. The restrictions are shown in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#sthref2328).

If you're using data pump (`expdp`) then yes, you can specify multiple `QUERY` clauses and specify which table each applies too, again as described in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#sthref154).

Comment: Look like need to create directory to use data pump. I do not have access to database server. Can export the dump to local?

Comment: @Thillaken - no, sadly, only to the server. [All Data Pump Export and Import processing, including the reading and writing of dump files, is done on the system (server) selected by the specified database connect string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#i1010293). I believe you can use a DB link if you have a local DB too, but doesn't sound like that helps you.

Comment: @Thillakan - sorry, I really must pay more attention to how user names are spelled...

Comment: we could export multiple table using exp, Example: EXP SCOTT/TIGER GRANTS=Y TABLES=(EMP,DEPT,MGR), Refer exp help=h

Comment: @Thillakan - well, yes, but that wasn't your question. You can't apply different `QUERY` restrictions to `EMP`, `DEPT` and `MGR` with a single `exp`.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I confused with a different question :(. Thanks @Alex

Comment: What is the syntax to export 2+ tables with individualized QUERY`s for each table? I am having trouble finding it

Comment: @Welsige - please ask a new question showing what you are trying and what error it throws.

Comment: @Welsige, you just supply multiple query arguments, e.g. `query=scott.emp:"where customer_id = 1001" query=scott.dept:"where DEPTNO = 10"`.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4150503/export-large-number-of-tables-with-query-condition