# Oracle exp, export with multiple queries

Tags: oracle, oracle-export-dump

Suppose I have 2 tables, `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` in production database, their primary keys are `A_ID` and `B_ID` respectively.

I want to export a row from `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` to a dump file using `exp` command. The data I want are the result of following 2 queries.

**TABLE_A**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE A_ID = 1001;
```

**TABLE_B**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE B_ID = 9999;
```

I searched around and found only following syntax that is close but still not exactly what I want because `TABLE_B` does not have column `A_ID`

```
exp userid=me/mypass@dbname tables=me.TABLE_A,me.TABLE_B query=\"WHERE A_ID=1001\"
```

I tried

```
exp userid=me/mypass@dbname tables=me.TABLE_A,me.TABLE_B query=me.TABLE_A:\"WHERE A_ID=1001\",me.TABLE_B:\"WHERE B_ID=9999\"
```

but it did not work, just got following error

```
LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'query'
```

Please help suggest how can I export a row from `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` in the same dump file.

---

## Update

(Moved the update to an answer according to @Alex suggestion)

Comment: If you've found your own solution, post it as an answer, not as part of your question. (And if you have a follow-up question, ask a new question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the old export (exp) then no, you'd need to do a separate export for each table.

If you're using data pump (expdp) then yes, you can specify multiple QUERY clauses and specify which table each applies too.

Source: [Multiple table export in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428872/multiple-table-export-in-oracle?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated my question according to your suggestion. But I have a new question: Is a ROWID is unique across the whole database? I appreciate if you may know the answer ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mehmet suggestion, I gave up the straight solution and started finding a work-around solution. (I cannot use `expdp` because I don't have access to the database server.

I create a table `EXP_ROW_ID` as follows

```
CREATE TABLE EXP_ROW_ID (ROW_ID VARCHAR(20));
```

Then I put the ROWID of the rows I want to export from the 2 tables

```
INSERT INTO EXP_ROW_ID SELECT ROWID FROM TABLE_A WHERE A_ID = 1001;
INSERT INTO EXP_ROW_ID SELECT ROWID FROM TABLE_B WHERE B_ID = 9999;
```

Then I export the dump using following command

```
exp userid=me/mypass@dbname tables=me.TABLE_A,me.TABLE_B query=\"WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT T.ROW_ID FROM EXP_ROW_ID T)\"
```

Comment: smart answer. unfortunately it is impractical for large tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this

expdp system/xxxxxx tables=TABLE_A query=\"WHERE A_ID = 1001\"